Realize transfer function with Op-Amps
I have this transfer function:
$$
H(s) = 15 \cdot \frac{(1k)^2}{s^2+500 s+(1k)^2} \cdot \frac{s+40}{s+300}
$$
I separated it into two stages, diving the \$k=15\$ so that both transfer functions have similar gain in \$w_0=1k\$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_1(s)&= 5 \cdot \frac{(1k)^2}{s^2+500 s+(1k)^2} \\[1.5em]
H_2(s)&= 3 \cdot \frac{s+40}{s+300}
\end{aligned}
$$
For \$H_1\$ I used a low pass Sallen-Key and I got all the values that work.
My problem is with \$H_2\$. I tried several configurations of \$Z_1\$ and \$Z_2\$ of a non inverting op amp but could not get any values that satisfy the transfer function. Anyone has any recommendation or knows what I am doing wrong.


You can choose both stages inverting or non-inverting too.

Without changing anything, you can proceed as in the figure where, however, you need to size the passive and reactive components:

you can also proceed as follows: obtain a third-order transfer function as in the figure and size the illustrated circuit:


There are two (relatively) simple realizations:
A) Non-inverting (from control theory: PD-T1 or "LEAD"-block):
Use the classical non-inverting opamp circuit with R2 in the feedback path and a series combination R1-C between opamp input and ground. This will result in a transfer function
H2(s)=[(R1+R2)/R1]N(s)/D(s) with
N(s)=[s+1/(R1+R2)C]  and D(s)=[s+1/R1C ]
B) Inverting
You can use the classical inverting opamp-configuration with the gain Acl=-Z2/Z1.
Both impedances Z1 and Z2 are to be realized as a R-C parallel combination.
If I am not wrong, the result is
H2(s)=- R1C1[(1/R1C1)+s] / R1C2[(1/R2C2)+s]
(Here, the common factor is C1/C2=3 and both RC products can be selected independently)

The overall transfer function \$\dfrac{s+40}{s+100}\$ can be reshaped to \$(s+40)\cdot\dfrac{1}{s+100}\$ so, with the split in the formula can you solve them separately as two cascaded stages now. Then bring both stages together.
It looks like the \$s+40\$ part can be made with an inverting op-amp with a parallel RC at its input and a resistor feedback. Can you take it from here now?

Rewriting the transfer function the proper way is key to understanding what it exactly does. We have a system featuring a dc gain of 2 (6 dB), followed by a second-order filter tuned at 159 Hz with a quality factor of 2. Then follows a pole/zero pair.
I first start by using the original transfer function with the correct units then I give it a little massage, as inspector Clouseau would say and there you go, you see where poles and zeroes are located:

Once you are there, a quick visit to OKAWA Electric Design site for the active filter, a bunch of resistances with an op-amp for the 6-dB gain and the result looks simple:

The simulated data from SIMetrix match the original transfer function you wanted.
